# How to execute postman test in Jenkins?

Tags: git, testing, jenkins, automation, postman

I have collection of postman and stored in git.
How I can tell to Jenkins to execute postman test after unit test or integration test?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Postman is just a chrome client for interacting with REST APIs, so you can just use CURL commands inside Jenkins.

Comment: @MattSchuchard thank you.

Comment: Have a look here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49441224/how-to-setup-a-jenkins-pipeline-for-postman-tests/

Answer (score 1):

You can use Newman, is a Collection Command Line Runner that Postman created and is the best solution you can have for this issue, I'm about to implementing it myself on ConcourseCI, but you can do it with Jenkins too.

As you already have the collection exported and stored in git it will be easy to implement the commands to run it, give a try!

Here's the link for Newman:
https://www.getpostman.com/docs/newman_intro

Answer (score 0):

The best way is to use Newman.. you have to export your collection and same collection you can execute  with Command line interface using newman, also have a feasibility to extract report in JSON, HTML..ect  format

you can refer https://www.getpostman.com/docs/v6/postman/collection_runs/command_line_integration_with_newman

You can trigger the build with same command through Jenkin.

here is example with jenkin
[image]